# Paypal API doesn't send info when transaction is canceled

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

is there a way to detect canceled transactions?
My API is working fine, but someone is cheating somehow, transaction pass verification and API get the info and credits are added to account, but after 30-45 sec transaction is canceled and I see only this message 
"The payment was cancelled and the money was returned to the sender's account."

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's what [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) is for. If a payment status changes, you get a notice sent to you when it happens.

Comment: But it doesn't, when someone start a dispute IPN send this info, but when transaction is canceled asap is done I don't get anything.